# Fastlane gym error regarding to firebase_crashlytics

Tags: ios, fastlane

We are using fastlane for IOS and Andorid apps, we use a github action for CI/CD to automate the process and over the last three weeks all our build fail with gym error regarding to firebase_crashlytics.

versions:
fastlane - v2.211.0
Flutter - v3.3.10
Ruby - v3.1.2

This is our fastfaile:

```
lane :closed_beta do
keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD
ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)

api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
  key_id: APPLE_KEY_ID,
  issuer_id: APPLE_ISSUER_ID,
  key_content: APPLE_KEY_CONTENT,            
  duration: 1200,            
  in_house: false
)

previous_build_number = latest_testflight_build_number(
  app_identifier: ENV['DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER'],
  api_key: api_key,
)

current_build_number = previous_build_number + 1

increment_build_number(
  xcodeproj: "./ios/Runner.xcodeproj",
  build_number: current_build_number
)

cocoapods(
  clean_install: true,
  podfile: './ios/'
)

match(
  type: 'appstore',
  app_identifier: ENV['DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER'],
  team_id: ENV['TEAM_ID'],
  team_name: ENV['TEAM_NAME'],
  platform: 'ios',
  readonly: true,
  keychain_name: keychain_name,
  keychain_password: keychain_password,
  api_key: api_key
)
mapping = Actions.lane_context[
  SharedValues::MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING
]
update_code_signing_settings(
  profile_name: mapping[ENV['DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER']],
  path: "./ios/Runner.xcodeproj",
  build_configurations: "Runner",
  team_id: ENV['TEAM_ID'],
  use_automatic_signing: false,
)
update_project_provisioning(
    xcodeproj: "./ios/Runner.xcodeproj",
    target_filter: "Runner",
    profile: ENV['redacted'],
)
gym(
  configuration: "Runner",
  workspace: "./ios/Runner.xcworkspace",
  scheme: "Release",
  export_method: "app-store",
  export_options: {
    provisioningProfiles: { 
        DEVELOPER_APP_ID => PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER
    }
  }
)
delete_temp_keychain(keychain_name)
```

end

And this is the log from /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/Runner-Runner.log:
2023-05-16 16:51:37.687 upload-symbols[45046:1043174] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path
2023-05-16 16:51:38.688 upload-symbols[45046:1043174] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path
Running upload-symbols in Build Phase mode
Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
Processing dSYMs...
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

```
▸ Running script '[firebase_crashlytics] Crashlytics Upload Symbols'
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [firebase_crashlytics]\ Crashlytics\ Upload\ Symbols /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gwpgnbrfqscwihenbweklmlbcztv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-25C950C41F1C8CB0C3864E36.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
(1 failure)
[13:56:06]: Exit status: 65
[13:56:06]: 
[13:56:06]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[13:56:06]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[13:56:06]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[13:56:06]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode_14.2.app'
[13:56:06]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[13:56:06]: 
[13:56:06]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[13:56:06]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") *** Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[13:56:06]: 
[13:56:06]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[13:56:06]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[13:56:06]: 
[13:56:06]: - Manually update the path using
[13:56:06]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[13:56:06]:
```

Comment: As mentioned in the error message, did you try setting Xcode path in your `fastfile`? Since it found multiple versions of Xcode.